# Range of Host IPs in the network

Tags: c#, network-programming

I am able to get the `IP address` and `Subnet Mask` programatically. Is there a way we could generate all addressable host IPs with these two information?

I am just trying to develop a simple `Ping Sweep` module for my application.

Thanks.

PS: I am using C# .NET 3.5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Calculate the first and last host IP addresses and then iterate over them sequentially. The first IP address is `(address & mask) + 1`. The last is `(address | ~mask) - 1`.

So if the network is `192.168.132.0` and the netmask is `255.255.255.0`, the first eligible host IP is:

```
(address & mask) + 1
(192.168.132.0 & 255.255.255.0) + 1
192.168.132.0 + 1
192.168.132.1
```

The last eligible host IP is:

```
(address | ~mask) - 1
(192.168.132.0 | ~(255.255.255.0)) - 1
(192.168.1.32.0 | (0.0.0.255)) - 1
192.168.132.255 - 1
192.168.132.254
```

So the valid host addresses are `192.168.132.1` through `192.168.132.254` inclusive.